# OS X Catalina: add user to sudoers

Tags: macos, terminal, catalina, sudo

Prior to OS X Catalina I could add a user to the sudoers by editing `/etc/sudoers` with an admin account.

With OS X Catalina, I can no longer do this as it seems that Catalina moved to a read-only root filesystem and so `/etc/sudoers` cannot be edited.

According to this [official Apple User Guide](https://support.apple.com/guide/directory-utility/about-the-root-user-dirub32398f1/mac), it appears that the sudoers file is now located at `/private/etc/sudoers`, but I am still unable to edit this file with an admin account.

What is the correct way to grant a user sudouers access in Catalina?

Comment: What do you mean by "can‘t be edited"?  Doesn‘t `sudo visudo` work on Catalina any longer? What error do you get if you run this?

Comment: Why was this down voted?  It's a valid question any normal Mac user could possibly have. +1

Comment: @Allan The user claims that the behaviour changed with Catalina (which it didn't), and doesn't show the actual command used. So it's hard to see what exactly went wrong. The answer is good though, and of general use.

Comment: It not clear and he’s mistaken, yes @nohillside, but down vote worthy?  That I disagree with.  We see way more question with less detail get flagged/closed, but not down voted.  I just think there are some here too eager to down vote and I believe it’s off putting to new(er) users.

Comment: @Allan I share the feelings regarding the apparent focus on downvote (and now, I didn't downvote, but maybe the two users who upvoted my initial comment did).

Comment: I'm experiencing the same thing the OP posted. I can't edit /etc/sudoers or /private/etc/sudoers
I can't use visudo, with or without sudo even though I should have admin rights

Answer (score 29, accepted):

It turns out that even an admin user needs to use sudo to edit the sudoers file at `/private/etc/sudoers` so the following did the trick to open the file for edit:

```
$ sudo visudo /private/etc/sudoers
```

As usual, a user can be added to the list of sudoers by adding a line such as this:

```
username ALL=(ALL) ALL
```

Comment: Given this answers the question you can accept your own answer to mark it as solved.

Comment: ...was this not the case prior to Catalina? That’s odd! O_O

Comment: In Debian as an alternative you can add <username> to the sudo group with `useradd`. This does not seem to work on Unix/Mac, `sudo` is not in `groups`.

Comment: The `sudoers` in /etc and /private/etc seem identical, no difference with the `diff` tool.

Answer (score 8):

If you want to be able to use sudo without typing a password:

```
sudo visudo
```

And add:

```
username        ALL = (ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL
```

Adding this gives any commands, including scripts, you execute in the terminal ability to run sudo without a prompt, which exposes you to increased risk of exploitation. Use with caution.

Comment: I advise extreme caution when doing this.  This is horribly insecure because you are literally giving admin rights with no authentication.

Comment: Right. Use with care, especially when executing scripts. But I think giving people options is useful, rather than not useful, so the downvote was unjustified (whoever it was).

Comment: Between you, me and the lamp post, the excessive down votes by an unknown few in the community is irksome.  I don't down vote unless egregious - like outright wrong and/or dangerous.  This answer could benefit from text highlighting the potential risks, but IMO, it's not down vote worthy.  However, +1 to offset.

Comment: Alright, I've added a warning.

Comment: This is the only solution to avoid password prompt. Adding the user to `admin` or `wheel` does not help.